# PowerApps dropdown, toggle and variable issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, dropdown, variable

I am hoping I can get some help with a issue I am having where a dropdown, toggle and variable are involved.  This is for a PowerApps that uses SharePoint online as the data source.

I have a dropdown, when the user selects "Employee", I need the toggle to default to true.

To do this, on the dropdown `OnChange` property I put, `If(dropdown.selected.value="Employee", Set(varEmployee, "Employee))`

On the toggle `default` property I put, `If(varEmployee="Employee", true, false)`
On the toggle `OnChange` property I put, `If(toggle.value=false, Set(varEmployee, "None")`

For when the toggle needs to be true it works fine, but if I need the toggle to be false it does not work.

When I select Employee from the dropdown, then toggle to false, It works fine until I click submit, for some reason as soon as I click submit, it is setting the variable to "Employee", and putting the toggle on true.  This happens after submit.

I have tried resetting the variable after submit, onsave, onview, on edit, I dont know why it does this.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more context for your app? What is the purpose of the toggle? If selecting Employee from the dropdown sets the toggle to true, what purpose does manually setting the toggle to false serve? It feels like there is supposed to be some kind of relationship between the dropdown and the toggle, however I'm not really understanding what it is.